# Photon, RPC not working, how can I fix my code?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rpc, photon

I'm trying to synchronize text in a unit between players, but I'm getting an error.
I just need to sync the text
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0l98U.png

````
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Photon.Pun;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

public class Sync : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    private PhotonView view;
    public Text textGame;
    public Text copied;

    void Start()
    {
        view = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
    }

    public void sync()
    {
        if(view.IsMine)
            view.RPC("ViewAll", RpcTarget.AllBuffered, textGame.text);
    }

    [PunRPC]
    public void ViewAll(string tG)
    {
        tG = copied.text;
        Debug.Log(tG);
    }

   
}```

пппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппппп
````

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the "view" variable has not been assigned and is therefore null.

- To assign it you can make that field public, and in the inspector you
  assign the photonView you want, I guess that of the player.
- Alternatively you can assign "view" not from the inspector but in a
  Start() or Awake() method. If the photonView you want to associate is
  on the same GameObject as the script, you can write like this:

  ```
   void Awake() 
   {
       view = GetComponent<PhotonView>(); 
   }
  ```
- However, the easiest answer is to replace "view" with "photonView".
  It will have the same result as the solutions described above, but it will be very simple.

  ```
   public void sync()
   {
       if(photonView.IsMine)
           view.RPC("ViewAll", RpcTarget.AllBuffered, textGame.text);
   }
  ```

I have not directly given you the simple slogan to make you fully understand the problem and to help you solve it.

Comment: Hi! Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271810/is-it-ok-to-ask-to-upvote-accept-my-own-answers and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323847/is-it-okay-to-ask-for-upvotes-in-a-question Asking for upvoted in the body of the question is considered noise.

Comment: @bolov Hello. Sorry for the mistake. I'm new and need to practice :). I was wondering: I found this link (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271815/19523897). As it is written, I did not know that positive votes could not be asked, and I will not do it again, but I can not even ask to accept the question? Sometimes it takes me hours to help a single user, and if they then see my response and don't accept it, even if it's thorough, friendly and patient, I'm sorry. It says that if it is an excellent answer, you can ask to accept it, with kindness and without pressure. I await your opinion: D

Comment: I understand writing a good answer takes a lot of time. After 15 min (the period the OP cannot accept answers) if the OP hasn't accepted any answer yet you can write a comment on the question itself.

Comment: Thanks for the advice: I will follow it :). If you have a second to dedicate to me, I have four curiosities: if I comment on my question, will the author be notified? And is there a way to quote users? If I leave a comment when there are already other comments, will all the authors of the other comments be notified? Is there a way to open a chat with some user? They are just curiosities that I could not find in the guidelines. Thanks for the support :)

Comment: Yes, when you comment on some's post that user gets notified. To "quote" users you use "@username" (it's called reply) (once you start typing "@" you get username autocomplete) and you can only reply to 1 user on a comment. The user replied to gets notified. From my experience the user also gets notified in other situations even when not explicitly replied to, one example is your above comment: I've received a notification even if you didn't use "@" as it's obvious you were replying to me.

Comment: There is also the [chat feature](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq) and you can [start a chat with one user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231544/how-can-i-start-a-chat-with-a-particular-user) but I've very rarely use the feature as comments should be about clarifying current posts and so all users should see them. So ... this conversation we are having shouldn't be in the comments because it is not about the question or answer, it's about site guidelines. But a little lenience hasn't hurt anybody. And starting a chat is so arduous.

Comment: @iFralex but its doesnt work i did photon view on object and do this again. And that doesnt work too

Comment: What doesn’t work specifically? Do you have instantiate the object with Photon.Instantiate? Are there any messages in the console?